# When to and Not to use alias for JOINs in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, alias

I used citibike_stations and citibike_trips from public data base and copied those tables.
So I have :
Dataset: Citibike_stations1
Tables - Stations and Trips.

Below is the query where I get error - "Unrecognized name:

SELECT
st.station_id,
st.name,
number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_fromstation,
***doubt1- number_of_rides is not a column so how will SQL select this***
FROM (
SELECT
start_station_id,
COUNT(*)number_of_rides
FROM
`leafy-racer-348015.citibike_stations1.trips` tr
GROUP BY start_station_id ) AS station_num_trips
INNER JOIN
`leafy-racer-348015.citibike_stations1.stations`st ON
st.station_id = tr.start_station_id
ORDER BY
number_of_rides DESC

Doubt2 -When I run this query, I get Unrecognized error in the line st.station_id=tr.start_station_id. But if I remove this alias, then it works fine.

I am referring this question from Google Data Analytics Course Wk3 Nested Queries Module. Earlier in the JOIN module, I understood that Aliases are necessary for the Join function to work. But here -it is opposite. Why?

Comment: Can't quite work out what you're asking, but I wonder if it's "how do I use an alias defined elsewhere in the same select?" -> you don't; you repeat the thing that calculates that alias. `SELECT MIN(AGE) as minimum_age, CASE WHEN MIN(AGE) > 18 THEN 'All Adults' END FROM Person`, (see how i use MIN(AGE) twice). Compare that form to this attempt, which does not work `SELECT MIN(AGE) as minimum_age, CASE WHEN minimum_age > 18 THEN 'All Adults' END FROM Person` - you can't use an alias declared in this select, in this select. If you want to use an alias, you make it in a subquery,use in the parent

Comment: *doubt1- number_of_rides* - format your question better; this looks like youre asking about a formula: `doubt1 - number_of_rides` i.e. "**doubt1 column, minus number_of_rides column**" but I think you actually mean "my first doubt is ..".

Comment: *Aliases are necessary for the Join function to work* - not necessarily true; unaliased table names can be used as they are. Aliasing is recommended though, and if a table is joined in twice it's necessary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've managed to work out what this is asking. First, let's format your query so it's legible (but still has errors):

```
SELECT 
  st.station_id, 
  st.name, 
  number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_fromstation,
FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT start_station_id, COUNT(*) as number_of_rides 
    FROM leafy-racer-348015.citibike_stations1.trips tr 
    GROUP BY start_station_id 
  ) station_num_trips 

  INNER JOIN leafy-racer-348015.citibike_stations1.stations st 
  ON 
    st.station_id = tr.start_station_id 

ORDER BY number_of_rides DESC
```

> number_of_rides is not a column so how will SQL select this

Sure it is. The subquery aliased by `station_num_trips` generates it from `COUNT(*)`.

SQL is just "rectagular blocks of data in, rectangular blocks of data out" - every SELECT produces a rectangular block of data, just like a table, that can be fed into another operation, like a JOIN, FROM or WHERE. It can even be fed into a SELECT if it's a single value. Your subquery here:

```
  ( 
    SELECT start_station_id, COUNT(*) as number_of_rides 
    FROM leafy-racer-348015.citibike_stations1.trips tr 
    GROUP BY start_station_id 
  ) station_num_trips
```

..took all the data in `trips`, threw all the columns away except the station id, counted the number of trips from that station, and produced a new block of data that was just `station id`, and the `count`: it measures 2 columns wide by N rows high (N is the number of unique station IDs). This is what gets joined in when you do the join; your 2 wide by N high block of data.

Trips might have had 1000 rows of the same station ID and 10 columns; they're all gone, collapsed into 1 row, 2 columns and a count of 1000 in the one row. This now behaves like a new table called `station_num_trips`

--

At every step columns and rows are added or removed, so basically all you're ever doing in SQL is cutting up, and joining together blocks of data, to form new blocks of data.

Tables often form the starting blocks, but they don't have to:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 as A UNION SELECT 2) x
```

This is perfectly valid; you could apply a where clause to remove rows, a JOIN to a table to add more columns and then SELECT those new columns or use them to produce more calculated values

---

There's no point aliasing your table in the subquery; there is only one table so it's obvious what you're referring to:

```
  ( 
    SELECT start_station_id, COUNT(*) as number_of_rides 
    FROM leafy-racer-348015.citibike_stations1.trips       --removed alias
    GROUP BY start_station_id 
  ) station_num_trips
```

Aliasing it also then led you to another mistake:

> When I run this query, I get Unrecognized error in the line `st.station_id=tr.start_station_id`. But if I remove this alias, then it works fine.

`tr` is an alias inside the subquery. It doesn't exist where youre using it. The whole subquery is aliased as `station_num_trips` so it's `station_num_trips.start_station_id` you need to use in your join condition, not `tr.start_station_id`. The `tr` alias is gone; you cannot access an subquery's alias from the parent query that wraps it.

You can, however, access a parent query's alias in a subquery (the other way round from what you have)

```
SELECT *              
FROM table1 x         <-- this is the parent query
WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT null FROM table2 y WHERE x.id = y.id)
                                          ^^^
                                  from the parent query
```

Doing this is a common way to coordinate a subquery's data with the main query data. Here this query asks "get me only x records where there is a matching record in table2" - it needs that coordination between the subquery and the main in order to work

---

Make use of indentation to keep straight in your mind what is a parent and what is a subquery. Small subqueries might fit all on one line, or a compact form where each line is lead by the block keyword. Larger queries should be spread out:

```
SELECT
  smiths.columnX,
  counted_things.column3,
  SUM(x.yz)

FROM
  (SELECT * FROM People WHERE name = 'SMITH') smiths

  JOIN (
    SELECT name, age, column3, COUNT(*) as columnX
    FROM TableA JOIN tableB On x = y
    WHERE column4 = 'something'
    GROUP BY name, age, column3
  ) counted_things
  ON 
    counted_things.name = smiths.Name AND 
    counted_things.age = smiths.Age AND
    ..

  JOIN sometable x ON x.whatever = counted_things.whatever

  JOIN anothertable y
  ON
    x.id = y.id AND
    ...

WHERE
  x.thing = 123

GROUP BY
  smiths.columnX,
  counted_things.column3
```

See how I'm using indentation to describe what level everything is operating at - the `SELECT FROM WHERE GROUP` etc are aligned; they belong to the same query. The data blocks int he FROM are indented and aligned with each other; subqueries have parentheses that align with other parentheses and table names. It's easy to pick out a subquery. It's easy to see what it joins to; `smiths, counted_things, sometable and anothertable` are indented the same, they're joined together and operate at the same level. Subqueries are indented inside thair brackets to clarify that they're subqueries

All this helps you use rules like "subqueries can access parent aliases but not the other way round" and "subqueries produce rows and columns that behave like new tables"